# Symfony and Zend Lucene highlighting

Tags: zend-framework, symfony1, symfony-1.4, zend-search-lucene, lucene-highlighter

I use symfony 1.4 and I use Zend Lucene search like in **[Jobbet](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/17)** And I need to make Search Results Highlighting, I read  **[this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.searching.html#zend.search.lucene.searching.highlighting)** , but I do not understend how it make in my case with symfony(

```
$ highlightedHTML = $ query-> highlightMatches ($sourceHTML);
```

What is $sourceHTML? And is it all makes by only one row?

**upd:**

```
 $ highlightedHTML = $ query-> highlightMatches ($sourceHTML);
```

It works in my model, but how it implement in my view?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @Dziamid I find this [link](http://ganeshhs.com/zend-framework/zend-search-lucene-part4-search-results-highlighting), I do not where I must do it, in my table class? probably better to use [this](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) ?Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not now , if it is right , but it is work :)
Just in view:

```
$query = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse($queryStr);
$highlightedHTML = $query->highlightMatches($sourceHTML);
```

In my case for example:

```
echo $query->highlightMatches($ad->getCompany())
```

Comment: @Herman it was question about symfony 1.4, there are no twig, and it was 2 years ago ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to store this highlighted HTML in your model. Or make a function that is accessible from the view. For example:

```
<?php
class Model {
  private $content;

  public function getContent(){
    return $this->content;
  }

  public function getContentHighlighted(){
    // Search term, usually in $_GET or $_POST
    $term = $_GET['searchterm'];
    // Parse query
    $query = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse($term);
    // Return highlighted
    return $query->highlightMatches($this->getContent());
  }

}
?>
```

In your view (like in this case: Twig) you use:

```
<h1>The content</h1>
{{model.getContentHighlighted}}
```